# Is it possible to rename Thunar's side pane default items?

Tags: rename, xfce, thunar, panel

[image]

I would like to display a different name of these items - that would indicate for example that one is windows partition, other ubuntu, etc.

Is it feasible?

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3486/13011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, in a different circumstance, as I was managing partitions in **Gparted**, I noticed the option 'Label' that could be accessed for unmounted partitions

[image]

[image]

This label is the one in Thunar's side pane.
Any partition, including Windows can be renamed in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not through thunar. Mapping a name directly with partition is something that not even supported by dolphin.

What you should do is add a disk label instead, for linux ones, use `tune2fs` to set a label, i.e to label the partition `/dev/sda1` with `Ubuntu` (**JUST AN EXAMPLE!**), you do a `sudo tune2fs -L Ubuntu /dev/sda1`

For windows one, just boot into your Windows and rename it in `My Computer` (Press <kbd>F2</kbd> when you selected the target drive, and type in the letter), afterwards, the drive would have a label displayed.

Comment: could you explain a bit "add a disk label instead, for linux ones, use tune2fs -L XX /dev/yyy to set a label"? what is that: a command to run in terminal i guess. but is it a general one with variables? could you explain or link to a tutorial, i'm newbie. or maybe just add some details (i'm using thunar in mint and lubuntu)

Comment: @cipricus updated the answer, if you also don't know how to figure out which partition is used by which OS, i'll add more stuff